# Widen border of UIButton?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, border, uistackview

I have a button inside a horizontal stack view and am trying to give it a border using the Runtime Attributes in Xcode. Here is what my storyboard looks like:

[image: storyboard]

When I run my app the text has no padding so the border fits very tight:

[image: runtimeApp]

Is there any way to make the border of the button fit a bit looser? I can't seem to make the UIButton bigger since it's in a stack view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  look at lowering the content hugging priority of the add button as both are UIButtons and have same compression resistance and content hugging priority and stack view algorithm in such cases stretches the leftmost view.

Comment: To complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a width constraint on the button.